# Two columns ListView with items of varying heights

Tags: android, listview

I want to create a two columns listView with items of varying heights like that:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuGeD.png)

I have try this [custom class](https://github.com/andersericsson/MultiColumnList/blob/master/ColumnListApp/src/main/java/com/jayway/columnlist/ColumnListView.java) found on GitHub and it was perfect but I have different problems because maybe the class is old (last update: 2014):

- Child Item's images with onClickListener block the custom listView's scrolling
- SwipeRefreshLayout appear always when scroll up (I want only when I am at the top of the list)

**[Edit] Solution:**

> *Proposed by Piyush*: 
>   [StaggeredGridLayoutManager with RecyclerView](http://android--code.blogspot.in/2015/12/android-recyclerview.html)

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: You can use StaggeredGridLayoutManager with RecyclerView: https://android--code.blogspot.in/2015/12/android-recyclerview.html

Comment: Thank You Piyush for your solution ! It works !!! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **StaggeredGridLayoutManager**

you can use StaggeredGridLayoutManager

```
private StaggeredGridLayoutManager gaggeredGridLayoutManager;
gaggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, 1);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gaggeredGridLayoutManager);
```

for more information follow this link [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a ScrollView instead? So you'll have a parent ScrollView containing just one RelativeLayout. Then you'll place two vertical LinearLayout inside the Relative one in which you are going to place your varying heights cells.
Pseudo-code follows:

```
<ScrollView>
  <RelativeLayout>
       <LinearLayout orientation="vertical">
         //insert you items here via GroupView.addView inside your activity
       </LinearLayout>
       <LinearLayout orientation="vertical">
       </LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
<ScrollView>
```

Comment: I am not sure that your solution is optimized but thank you for your help!